# Jupyter Notebook Installation on python 3.8 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 79, in 
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 17, in 
from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 26, in 
from traitlets import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'Callable' from 'traitlets' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/traitlets/**init**.py)

Answer (score 0):

Run command:

```
pip install jupyter
```

It worked for me.